# C# start program with arguments containing strings

Tags: c#

I want to start a program using this code:

```
private void PBox_Banner_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string JavaPath = @"C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\bin\javaw.exe";
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.FileName = JavaPath;
    startInfo.Arguments = @"-Xmx1024-jar "D:\Log4-cg.jar"";
    Process.Start(startInfo);
}
```

The problem is that I have to use a string within the argument string.

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Desktop.

Comment: Would putting 'D:\Log4-cg.jar' in 's instead of "s help?

Comment: @farhad-alinoo No because then Java crashs.

Comment: You should scape character `"-Xmx1024-jar \"D:\\Log4-cg.jar\"";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doubling up on the quotes should fix it.

```
startInfo.Arguments = @"-Xmx1024-jar ""D:\Log4-cg.jar""";
```

Comment: Thank you it works, but i have to wait 8 minutes undit i can accept you answer.

Comment: Scarjit: You may either do as suggested here, or simply use apostrophes as mentioned in the comment to your question by @FarhadAliNoo.

Answer (score 0):

If David's solution doesn't work, the old-school fallback should:

```
startInfo.Arguments = "-Xmx1024-jar \"D:\\Log4-cg.jar\"";
```